Python logger: a different log record attribute for each thread
My use case is as follows: I have a server that handles requests, and for each request I'd like the log record to contain a user_id. I'd like to make it as seamless as possible for other developers in my team, such that they can simply import logging and use it, without passing user_id around.
Here's a MWE, but, as you can see, its not always working:
import logging
import threading
import time

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, user_id: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.local = threading.local()
        self.local.user_id = user_id

    def filter(self, record):
        record.user_id = getattr(self.local, 'user_id', 'NoValue')
        return True  # Returning True ensures the log message is processed

# Set up logging
logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add a handler
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(user_id)s - %(message)s')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# logger.info("This is a test message.")

def worker(user_id: str):
    logger.addFilter(ContextFilter(user_id=user_id))
    logger.info("message 1")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    logger.info("message 2")
    

t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=("user1",))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=("user2",))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

This is the output:
2024-11-20 17:46:39,780 - INFO - user1 - message 1
2024-11-20 17:46:39,780 - INFO - user2 - message 1
2024-11-20 17:46:40,284 - INFO - NoValue - message 2
2024-11-20 17:46:40,285 - INFO - user2 - message 2

What am I missing here?

The logging module implements the logger as a singleton, so you need to add a logger or at least a handler per thread, your current function keeps adding filters to the same logger-handler. logger is not thread safe.

Each thread is creating its own thread-local object, which is wrong, a thread-local object should only be created once then accessed from many threads.
Just have one filter, and have each thread modify its thread-local version of this id. (Although all threads read and write to the same threading.local() each thread sees different attributes if it reads or write to it, that's what thread-local means)
import logging

import threading
import time


class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.local = threading.local()

    def set_id(self, user_id):
        self.local.user_id = user_id

    def filter(self, record):
        record.user_id = getattr(self.local, 'user_id', 'NoValue')
        return True  # Returning True ensures the log message is processed


# Set up logging
logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add a handler
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(user_id)s - %(message)s')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

global_filter = ContextFilter()
logger.addFilter(global_filter)

def worker(user_id: str):
    global_filter.set_id(user_id)
    logger.info("message 1")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    logger.info("message 2")


t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=("user1",))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=("user2",))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

INFO - user1 - message 1
INFO - user2 - message 1
INFO - user1 - message 2
INFO - user2 - message 2

(time stamp omitted for privacy)
